# Prove user is logged in with Session key express

Tags: express, authentication

I am following a [login tutorial](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/examples/auth/index.js) from express.

First of all they generate a SessionID for any request, as the middleware is on top of the script.

For `app.post(/login)` they check username and password (hashed and salted) against database data (dummy db in the example).

When user authenticates they just set `session.user=user`

Now say the user tries to access `get(/page1)`. How do I prove the user has a loggin ID given by the server, so that user can access `/page1`?

It seems they test if **session.user** is defined, but
I can't see how this is secure...

Answer (score 0):

Follow these points:

- Send the token in `Authorization` header
- Pass the request to the authentication middleware (auth.middleware.js) before you process it (before you pass it to the next request handler).
- Anyone who has the token can access the resource so you should set an expiry time for that token
- It is your choice to either generate a new access token on each request or give it an expiry time without generating a new token on each request.
- After you make sure that the token hasn't expired yet and that the user exists, then you can call `next()` to go the next RequestHandler, which is most probably your controller that has your logic there.
- You can pass your use in Request by making `req.user = user`;